# Overheat problem with Ubuntu 15.04 on Asus K55VD

Tags: nvidia, asus, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, overheating

I got [this laptop](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/review/laptops/asus-k55vd-review-3373744/).

The issue is with the nVIDIA / Bubmlebee/Optimus.

Drivers are correctly installed, no black screen. Optirun is working correctly. However, after a period of about 10 minutes working, the machine starts to overheat. All the fans are running at their max, the CPU cores are up to ~80 degrees celsius.

Is there any solution for this?

Currently I am running Windows 8.1, because of the fact that this is running smoothly, the laptop is constantly cool. However, I want to run Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | egrep 'VGA|3D' -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't specific of NVIDIA. What is been overheated are the CPU cores, and also started happening to me with Ubuntu 15.04 running Intel graphics.

My brother also has an Intel graphics laptop, and suffers from this problem from a long time ago. Even when we changed the thermal paste for a high quality one (Artic Silver), the laptop is still shutting.