# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Overheating: Shutting down my machine

Tags: overheating

I'm a noob in Linux and yesterday I wanted to try Ubuntu dual booted in my machine so that I can start learning it. But I had to do something wrong= Accidentally deleted all of the partitions also clean wiped my windows.

Now the problem: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit in my HP pavilion dv6 powered by amd processor since last night. From then this is the third time my machine shut down due to over heating.

I've seen people posting their config using terminal command but I'm totally lost cuz I'm illiterate in Unix commands. If you can walk me through then I'll be able to post them.

Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance
Raiyeem

Comment: You have the same problem as [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632786/overheat-problem-with-ubuntu-15-04-on-asus-k55vd/633918).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the problem with overheating and shutting down is hardware related. I've repaired quite a few pc/laptops with the same problem, and 90% of the time it's because the thermal paste on the cpu has degraded and a huge ammount of dustcollection (almost like a small carpet covering the whole intake) near the coolingfan's air intake. Just open your pc (carefully), remove the heatsink that's on top of the cpu (in a laptop thats going to be a piece of solid copper that connects te cpu with the coolingfan. remove any thermalpaste residu with a cottonswap and some pharmaceutical alcohol. Apply some new thermalpaste (NOT TO MUCH), remove all the dust, put everything back together, and your pc should stop overheating.

Comment: Thanks mate I'll try to follow your instructions and let you know the result.
sorry for the late reply.